# LINQ FirstOrDefault check for default value

Tags: c#, linq

How can you check to see whether the object returned by the `FirstOrDefault` LINQ function is in fact the default?

For example:

```
Contact contact = dbo.contact
                     .Where(m => m.contactName == "Stackoverflow")
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there an alternative way to check whether the contact above is default value instead of using the following?

```
if (!contact.contactName.Equals("Stackoverflow"))
    // do something
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You wouldn't need to perform that equals check because your query only returns objects where the contantName is `Stackoverflow`. When you use `FirstOrDefault` it returns `null` if no objects were found so you can do

```
if(contact == null)
    do something
```

You know it's a reference type if Contact is a class so it's default value would be null. You can, however, check it's the default type of any object (reference or value) by using `default`.

```
if(contact == default(Contact))
    do something
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can possibly make your code more efficient by using the overload of `FirstOrDefault` that takes a predicate.

```
FirstOrDefault(m => m.contactName == "Stackoverflow")
```

You can also change the default value returned if your program needs to work with something other than a `null` or `0`. For example

```
Contact defaultContact = new Contact();
defaultContact.ContactName = "StackExchange";

Contact contact = dbo.contact.Where(m=>m.contactName == "Stackoverflow")
                             .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultContact).First();
```

The above will return the `defaultContact` object if no other object was found (instead of returning null). If you do this then you don't need to check for `null` or `default(T)` because you know you have a `Contact` object.

Comment: One more note - it's better to use `FirstOrDefault(m => m.contactName == "Stackoverflow")`

Comment: This works only if `contact` is reference type, using `default()` is better.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, what if i am using it as a query? i.e contact = (from c in contact where contactName = "stackoverflow" select new contact{ }).FirsOrdefault() ?

Comment: @RajuKumar It would be the same result. On the next line you'd check the value of `contact` and see if it's equal to `default(Contact)` or `null`.

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` - Wow... I never knew about this.. that is so much better than testing non null-able objects if they are null! Thanks!!

Comment: @ppumkin - you're welcome :) Always nice to come across neat little features like this

Answer (score 12):

`FirstOrDefault` will return `null` for reference types and `default` for value types. Thus your test is invalid. In orther to check wheteher the value is default, you should compare it with `default (Type)`:

```
Contact contact = dbo.contact.FirstOrDefault(m => m.contactName == "Stackoverflow");

if (!object.Equals(contact, default (Contact)))
    // Is not default
```

The code above will work with either `struct Contact` or `class Contact`. We also assume that `default (Contact)` is never a valid return value of our query.

Comment: You should provide some example code, this would be the best check.

Comment: I kept getting errors when trying to use `==`. This answer worked without errors.

Answer (score 5):

FirstOrDefault() stands for first element, if not found then "Default" value of that type. It internally uses the `default` keyword to return the default value.

**usage**: `return default(Contact) or default(int)`

for e.g. if it's a value type let say `int` then it'll return 0. In case of reference types it'll return "`Null`" etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Contact contact = dbo.contact.where(m=>m.contactName!="" &&m.contactName!=null && m.contactName == "Stackoverflow").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `FirstOrDefault` returns item which you've requested of `default` value for collections type. 
In case of references it's `null`, in case of int - `0` etc.