# How to retrieve data from query instead of foreach loop?

Tags: c#

I'm trying get data from query, i'm having luck with `foreach` but I don't want to loop in order to get data.

Sample of how I get data:

```
using (var db = new VeterinaryModelContainer())
{
    var owner = from b in db.Owners
                orderby b.Surname
                select b;
    var pets = from b in db.Pets
               select b;
    foreach (var OwnerName in owner)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} |", 
            OwnerName.Surname, 
            OwnerName.Forename));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not even sure how that is working, there is no collection named `owner` shown in your code.

Comment: Where is `owner` defined? What are you going to do with the data once you get it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and then provide a [mcve].

Comment: sorry i added in query for owner, still stuck on how to get the data without the need for foreach, thanks.

Comment: there is still no `owner` in your code. I am going to [edit] it for you because I believe I know what you are trying to convey.

Comment: So you are printing out the results of your query. Something you do not want to do? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to retrieve data from each of the tables and print them to console, only way i know how to access the data is through the foreach. for example numbers column could have 1,2,2,3,4, i want to access the data and display them

Comment: What's wrong with foreach/looping?

Comment: What is wrong with `foreach`? It is the proper language construct for executing statements against every element in a collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are religiously against ForEach loops, you can get rid of it, I suppose.  Change this:

```
foreach (var OwnerName in owner)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} |", 
        OwnerName.Surname, 
        OwnerName.Forename));
}
```

to this

```
Console.WriteLine
(
    string.Join
    (
        Environment.NewLine, 
        owner.Select
        (
            o => string.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} |", o.Surname, o.Forename)
        )
    )
);
```

Not sure it improves readability, but we sure kicked ForEach to the curb!

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting limited content, say one result item, simply use `.FirstOrDefault()` here is an example:

[LINQ FirstOrDefault check for default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184166/linq-firstordefault-check-for-default-value)

If you are expecting multiple rows, looping is a good approach.